# Bug al ver la información completa de un producto en php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html5

estoy creando una web donde hay cierta cantidad de productos recibidos por MySql y quiero agregarle un boton de ver más información. Sin embargo, cuando le doy click me muestra la información pero de todas las propiedades. Por ejemplo, al darle click en "click here to view" la idea es que me muestre la información de la propiedad únicamente, sin embargo, me muestra la de todas las propiedades.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo de cómo se ve, en el nombre me sale todos los nombres juntos, yo quisiera que solo me salga "apartamento", "hermosa propiedad" etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código que he usado en php para enviar la información de todas las propiedades:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $searchResultHTML .= '
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="card-box-a card-shadow">
                        <div class="img-box-a">
                            <img src="img/'. $row['imagen'] .'" alt="Propiedades en Costa Rica" class="img-a img-fluid">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-overlay">
                            <div class="card-overlay-a-content">
                                <div class="card-header-a">
                                    <h2 class="card-title-a">
                                        <a href="#">'. $row['nombre'] .'</a>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body-a">
                                    <div class="price-box d-flex">
                                        <span class="price-a">Precio | $ '. $row['precio'] .'</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="View/propiedad.php?'. $row['id'] .'" class="link-a">Click here to view
                                    <span class="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer-a">
                                    <ul class="card-info d-flex justify-content-around">
                                        <li>
                                            <h4 class="card-info-title">Provincia</h4>
                                            <span class="centrar-span">'. $row['provincia'] .'</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <h4 class="card-info-title">Cuartos</h4>
                                            <span class="centrar-span">'. $row['cuartos'] .'</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <h4 class="card-info-title">Garajes</h4>
                                            <span>'. $row['garaje'] .'</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <h4 class="card-info-title">Baños</h4>
                                            <span>'. $row['banos'] .'</span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
            }
```

funcion que valida el id de la propiedad

```
public function getNombre($id){
        $this->id = $id;
        $sqlQuery = "
            SELECT DISTINCT(nombre)
            FROM ".$this->productTable." 
            WHERE status = '1' AND id =" .$this->id;
        return  $this->getData($sqlQuery);
    }
```

Código para mostrar la información de una única propiedad

```
<?php
    include '../model/conexion.php';
    $product = new Product();   
    if(!isset($_GET["id"])) die("no se envio el id");
    // filtramos la variable
    $id = filter_var ( $_GET["id"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
?>

<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
          <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb-box d-flex justify-content-lg-end">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                <a href="../index.html">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                <a href="../property-grid.php">Properties</a>
              </li>
              <?php         
              $nombre = $product->getNombre($id);
              foreach($nombre as $nombreDetails){   
              ?>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active productDetail nombre" aria-current="page" value="<?php echo $nombreDetails["nombre"]; ?>"><?php echo $nombreDetails["nombre"]; ?></li>
              <?php    
              }
              ?>
            </ol>
          </nav>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en la llamada haces

```
if(!isset($_GET["id"])) die("no se envio el id");
// filtramos la variable
$id = filter_var ( $_GET["id"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
// la pasamos como argumento
$nombre = $product->getNombre($id);
```

ahora en al funcion

```
// recibimos $id como parametro
public function getNombre($id){
        // cambiamos le valor de $this->id
        $this->id = $id;
        $sqlQuery = "
            SELECT DISTINCT(nombre)
            FROM ".$this->productTable." 
            WHERE status = '1' AND id =" .$this->id;
        return  $this->getData($sqlQuery);
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Bryro tu comentario es de gran ayuda, sin embargo cuando los realizo me sale el suiguiente error:

Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Product::getNombre(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\EstateAgency\View\propiedad.php on line 100 and exactly 1 expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\EstateAgency\model\conexion.php:166 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\EstateAgency\View\propiedad.php(100): Product->getNombre() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\EstateAgency\model\conexion.php on line 166

Comment: Ya he actualizado la pregunta con los datos que estoy usando.

Comment: Dice que no le tas pasando argumentos intenta validad antes correji

Comment: Si en efecto no se envía el Id, cómo lo podría solucionar? Lo extraño es que en la URL si sale el id mira http://localhost:81/EstateAgency/View/propiedad.php?3

Comment: no le tienes nombre en tu href debes modificarlo por `'href="View/propiedad.php?id='. $row['id'] .'"` no le estas poniendo nombre

Comment: Te agradezco mucho! Me ha servido un monton!